# How to get windows path with backslash from elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying out few things on windows with emacs. In my case, I need to return the file path with backslash from elisp. But elisp always return the path with slash,etc.

```
(expand-file-name "text.log" "d:\\ProgramData\\temp")
=> d:/ProgramData/temp/text.log
```

My requirement:

```
(expand-file-name "text.log" "d:\\ProgramData\\temp")
=> d:\ProgramData\temp\text.log
```

It can be done with regexp, but I need more simple way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does `convert-standard-filename` in `(elisp) Standard File Names` fit your need?

Comment: Notice that this is not the intended use of `convert-standard-filename`, so it may fail in some cases (e.g. return a name which does not refer to the same file).

Comment: @Stefan: Agreed. But I also do not understand luozengbin's purpose, because Emacs and some tools in Windows can handle slash as well. On such systems `converter-standard-filename` will return a different filename, the original filename is invalid. If luozengbin want to pass this name to other tools, the renaming may be the correct behavior.

Comment: hi. thanks for you help. i want pass the filename to other tools.but the tools does not supported posix path.so i need to convert it.

Comment: @luozengbin `converter-standard-filename` will return a different name, e.g. (converter-standard-filename ".f") ==> "_f" on MS-DOS according to the `info`. If ".f" on MS-DOS is an invalid filename, "_f" may be your want.

Answer (score 7):

Of course `(subst-char-in-string ?/ ?\\ <file>)` should do the trick.  But note also that slashes work almost everywhere in Windows (the only tool I know that doesn't support them is the default "shell" (command.com, cmd.exe, or some such name)) so maybe you don't even need this conversion.